# How to add multiple entities in same transaction with auto generated id?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this in a loop

```
theTag = new ReportAdminTag() { Text = tag.Text };
_context.ReportAdminTag.Add(theTag);
_context.Entry(theTag).State = EntityState.Detached;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

but the second time through it throws an error

> The instance of entity type 'ReportAdminTag' cannot be tracked because
>   another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being
>   tracked

The ID's are both the default Guid because I'm using mssql newid() to generate ids.

Comment: When dealing with a `Guid` type, I find it much easier to let the client generate the Id (`Guid.NewGuid()`) instead of the server.  It has the benefit of not requiring a round-trip to get a generated Id.

Comment: Using gb network controller, many concurrent roundtrips for less than 1 kb are no significant impact for performance.

Comment: Never call `SaveChanges` in a loop - it degrades a performance. Call it out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks I was doing there b/c I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working, and I thought that might help.  Turns out I just need to regenerate my code as something was not synced with my schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-ran Scaffold-DbContext to generate my code from the database and things started working.  I probably made some minor change that wasn't resulting in an error and instead in this strange behavior.

Lesson here is don't go on vacation with uncompleted work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds there is problem on EF implemention, associated to EF Core's InMemory Provider.

However it can also occurs (duplication) on SQL Server, associated to result value of NewID() or NewSequentialID() function.

So it seems will be ***more safety*** if you create any guid helper to help EF when add a new entity which contains a guid column.

I suggest to combine Guid.NewId() value with any Random value to generate 32 bytes base85 encoded (varchar(32)*).

*) set guid column type to varchar(32).